# Merge cells and content in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, onenote, onenote-api, vba

I have a table in OneNote 2013 with 200 rows and 8 columns. The data looks something like this:

[image]

I have been tasked with transfering it to Excel. However, a simple copy and paste yields:

[image]

Is there a way that I might be able to make it look more like the original, or something like this:

[image]

I know the basics of VBA and I have a guess that I could use the fact that Column A is always shown as spanning even is the number of bullet points, etcetera changes.

Comment: Can't you save onenote files as .xls or .xlsx? Might be worth a try? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-a-OneNote-table-to-an-Excel-worksheet-f693d0ec-aad7-4441-9596-e5e1e641935d

Comment: @user1274820 it causes the same issues